# React Native Text element doesn't respect last line break

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following code to display some content with `Text`:

```
const ListItem = ({content}) => {
  return <Text>{content}</Text>
}
```

Given `content` a value with `\n`s (`"Lorem\nthe\nipsum"`), the above code still display line breaks nicely. However, if `content` ends with `\n`, for example: `"This is a sample text\n"`, `Text` somehow dismisses the last `\n` and does not display the corresponding line break. Is that an expected behavior, and is there a way to make `Text` respect the last `\n`?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you try this workaround - `<Text>{content.replace('<br/>', '\n')}</Text>`

Answer (score 0):

It will not dismiss that, I think your problem lies within your styling of the `ListItem`.

Just try your `<Text>{content}</Text>` outside of your ListItem and you will see that new line character works at the end of a string.

Comment: I tried and confirmed that the last new line character doesn't work... It seem always display n line breaks if I specify n + 1 line breaks.